# Soap call slower on remote server

Tags: java, xml, soap

I have a Java server application that do some Soap calls to a another distant server.

I have put my Java server app on a remote server with tomcat 8.5. And when I do Soap calls, it takes the double of time whereas it is faster from my local machine with tomcat 8.5 on Eclipse.

Do you know why ?

Here is the code for my soap client :

```
public class SoapHelper {

public String server   = "";
public String username = "";
public String password = "";
public String session  = "";  // this is the session id returned by the server upon successful login
private SOAPConnection con = null;
private MessageFactory mf = null;

public String service = "";
public String method  = "";
public String request  = "";  // this is what we send to the server
public String response = "";  // this is what the server return to us

public SoapHelper(String server) {
  this.server = server;
}

private String getURI() {
  return "https://" + this.server + this.session;
}

private SOAPMessage makeMessage(String nodeName, String xmlStr) throws Exception {

  SOAPMessage message = this.mf.createMessage();
  SOAPEnvelope envelope = message.getSOAPPart().getEnvelope();

  envelope.addNamespaceDeclaration("xsi", "http://www.w3.org/1999/XMLSchema-instance");
  envelope.addNamespaceDeclaration("xsd", "http://www.w3.org/1999/XMLSchema");

  SOAPBody body = envelope.getBody();

  SOAPElement element = body.addChildElement(envelope.createName("ns1:" + this.method));
  element.addAttribute(envelope.createName("xmlns:ns1"), "urn:" + this.service);
  element.addAttribute(envelope.createName("ns1"), "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding");

  SOAPElement ele2 = element.addChildElement(envelope.createName(nodeName));
  ele2.addAttribute(envelope.createName("xsi:type"), "xsd:string");
  ele2.addTextNode(xmlStr);

  message.saveChanges();

  return message;
}

private void doConnect()
{
  try {
    SOAPConnectionFactory conFactory = SOAPConnectionFactory.newInstance();
    this.con = conFactory.createConnection();
    this.mf = MessageFactory.newInstance();
  } catch(Exception e) {}
}

public boolean doRequest(String service, String method, String xml) 
{
this.service = service;
this.method  = method;
this.request = "";
this.request = xml;

try {
    URL endpoint = new URL(this.getURI());
    SOAPMessage message = this.makeMessage("msgstr", this.request);
    SOAPMessage retval = this.con.call(message, endpoint);
    //extraction du XML en String lisible du message SOAP
    this.response = extractXML(retval);
} catch (Exception e) {
    this.response = e.getMessage();
}
return true;
}

private String extractXML(SOAPMessage message) throws Exception {

    ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    message.writeTo(out);
    String returnxml = new String(out.toByteArray());
    DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
    Document document = db.parse(new InputSource(new StringReader(returnxml)));
    Element root = document.getDocumentElement();
    Node msg = root.getLastChild();

    return msg.getTextContent();
  }

private String getSession() throws Exception {

    DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
    Document document = db.parse(new InputSource(new StringReader(this.response)));
    Element root = document.getDocumentElement();

    return root.getAttribute("sessionid");
}

public void authenticate(String username, String password){

this.username = username;
this.password = password;

 try {
   String xml="<Message messageid='0'><Entity name='REF_LOGIN'>";
   xml+="<Property name='login_cd' value='" + this.username + "' type='string'/>";
   xml+="<Property name='password' value='" + this.password + "' type='string'/>";
   xml+="<Property name='machine_name' value='" + getMachineName() + "' type='string'/>";
   xml+="</Entity></Message>";
   doConnect();
   doRequest("Login","Authenticate",xml);
   this.session = this.getSession();
 }catch(Exception e)
 {
   this.session = e.getMessage();
 }
}
```

Comment: Can you provide some code?? And be a bit more specific?

Comment: What type of code ? my Soap client ?

Answer (score 0):

Most probably its Network bandwidth issue(if not others), because when you send the SOAP message from one machine to another remote machine, it needs to travel back and forth to the network and if message size is huge, the network bandwidth must be issue and taking lot to overall time.

As an example.

> If Network travel time =500 ms
>
> SOAP servic= 400 ms
>
> Then total time for remote server= 400+500 ms(which ~2*400 ms).

Here are some pointers to look into it.

1)Try to log how much time the server took in processing, the entry point to end of service, if its exact same or close to what you get in local, then its proved that its network issue *only*.

Network latency issues could be dealt many ways. Choosing nearby data centre, tunnelling, dedicated network connectivity etc.

2)If its not the above case, you might be trying to connect to remote database or something else in SOAP service which again may have network bandwidth issue or something(like capacity of database or indexes missing or huge data as compared to local) else but that proves that its not the network bandwidth issue, and you need to resolve that.

Hope this gives some context, though to get accurate answer you need to add more details to your question.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have done some logs for my service. And I can confirm that the time for the service is slower in remote than in local. And it is the soap process that takes the double time in remote.

Comment: So if it is a network bandwith issue, how do I resolve it ?